# cumalativive the all other columns expect date column in python ML with cumsum()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have stock data set like

```
     **Date        Open        High  ...       Close   Adj Close    Volume**
0 2014-09-17  465.864014  468.174011  ...  457.334015  457.334015  21056800
1 2014-09-18  456.859985  456.859985  ...  424.440002  424.440002  34483200
2 2014-09-19  424.102997  427.834991  ...  394.795990  394.795990  37919700
3 2014-09-20  394.673004  423.295990  ...  408.903992  408.903992  36863600
4 2014-09-21  408.084991  412.425995  ...  398.821014  398.821014  26580100
```

I need to cumulative sum the columns `Open,High,Close,Adj Close, Volume`

I tried this `df.cumsum()`, its shows the the error time stamp error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for processing trade data is best create `DatetimeIndex`:

```
#if necessary
#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

And then if necessary cumulative sum for all column:

```
df = df.cumsum()
```

If want cumulative sum only for some columns:

```
cols = ['Open','High','Close','Adj Close','Volume']
df[cols] = df.cumsum()
```